# How to change all the tables in my database to UTF8 character set?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, alter

My database is not in UTF8, and I'd like to convert all the tables to UTF8, how can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset dbname > dump.sql
sed -r 's/latin1/utf8/g' dump.sql > dump_utf.sql
mysql --user=username --password=password --execute="DROP DATABASE dbname; CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
mysql --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=utf8 dbname < dump_utf.sql
```

Comment: And hopefully your database doesn’t contain “latin1” inside any of the content, such as blog posts about character encoding… else your users may have grounds for a lawsuit if your post conversion website is suddenly offering erroneous database commands!

Comment: after the sed: uconv --from-code latin1 --to-code utf8 dump_utf.sql > dump_utf_fixed.sql

Answer (score 47):

For single table you can do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tab CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For the whole database I don't know other method than similar to this:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1575/convert-all-mysql-tables-and-fields-to-utf8

Comment: For those without command line access, you can quickly run `SHOW TABLES;` in your database, paste them into NimbleText at http://nimbletext.com/live and then use this pattern to generate the change script: `ALTER TABLE \`$0\` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: It apply for a 125MB data base?'

Answer (score 37):

replace `my_database_name` with your database name

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;')
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name' AND TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW';
```

this will build lots of queries which you can run

Comment: You should also add ` AND Table_Type != 'VIEW'`

Comment: I would suggest at the same time going not to utf8 but utf8mb4 so that astral plane characters such as emoji can also be stored.

Answer (score 1):

To change the collation in phpMyAdmin just follow this simple steps:

## Method 1

- open phpMyAdmin and select your database.
- After click on database click on operation tab.
  [image]
- Next, Scroll down the page, you will see the collation section.

  - set the collation do you want and click the checkbox.
  - your collation will be updated.
    [image]

*Note:* If you find any difficulty using `method 1` follow `method 2` using sql command line.

## Method 2

**Using command Line**

- Open `phpMyAdmin` and click on `SQL` tab.
  [image]
- Next, write command for changing the collation for your database.

```sql
# syntax command:

ALTER DATABASE your_db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE write_collation;

# e.g:
ALTER DATABASE temprory CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, use Percona's tool kit. I'd audit your indices before updating to utf8mb4 as there are issues with key length.

```
SELECT CONCAT('pt-online-schema-change --alter "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci" t=', TABLE_NAME, ',D=DB_NAME,u=USER_NAME --statistics --execute') 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME' AND TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW' AND TABLE_COLLATION NOT LIKE '%utf8%';
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have several schemas due to a bad migration.

Joining the other answers I did an ALTER command generator in this case to charset=latin1 and collate=latin1_general_ci for all the tables of all the schemas that doesn`t match latin1_general_ci

Hope it helps.

```
    SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', tbl.ts,'.',tbl.tn, ' CHARACTER SET latin1
    COLLATE latin1_general_ci, CHANGE COLUMN \`', tbl.tc, '\` \`'
    ,tbl.tc,'\` ', tbl.tct, ' CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 
    latin1_general_ci;' ) command FROM (SELECT table_schema ts, table_name 
    tn, column_name tc, COLUMN_TYPE tct FROM information_schema.columns  
    WHERE collation_name != 'latin1_general_ci' AND table_schema not in
    ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema','sys')) tbl;
```