# Migration of character set from latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-5.6

I need to change the character set of my schema and all tables in schema from '**latin1**' to '**utf8**'. I already have data in the present schema .so what is the way to migrate character set from '**latin1**' to '**utf8**'
Database size is 200 GB.backup and restore is needed for migration of character set.Please help me

Comment: [There is already an answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150256/how-to-change-all-the-tables-in-my-database-to-utf8-character-set)

Comment: @DennisY.Parygin I know the command but do i need to back up the data and restore again for previous data also to be in utf8 character set. (or) Simple command will do changes for previous data also.

Answer (score 1):

Do this for each table

```
ALTER TABLE tab CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Or read this: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html

Or convert your sqldump using this
[Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)