# MySQL dump file has some issue with foreign key constraint. referenced column '**' in foreign key constraint '**' are incompatible

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

I would like to import SQL dump file, some how it's not working.
I got this error when I try to import data.

```
Referencing column 'originator_id' and referenced column 'name' in foreign key constraint 'fk_rails_79d8c4ccda' are incompatible.
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `loan_fee_shares`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `loan_fee_shares` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `originator_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'belongs to [0,1] set',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `deactivated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_rails_79d8c4ccda` (`originator_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_79d8c4ccda` FOREIGN KEY (`originator_id`) REFERENCES `originators` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `originators`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `originators` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_originators_on_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: You need to move the `originators` table before `loan_fee_shares`.

Comment: You probably have an existing `originators` table with different definition of the `name` column, so you need to recreate the table first to make them compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this for someone who might have the same issue in the future.

`Barmar` has a good point. and I moved originators table to before loan_fee_shares. But I still had an issue.

and It had an issue with `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`, I had to change it to `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`. and It works.

I suggest that change all your tables to the same character set.

[How to change all the tables in my database to UTF8 character set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150256/how-to-change-all-the-tables-in-my-database-to-utf8-character-set)